# Не работает форма вывода комментария

Tags: php, post, form

Есть такая форма, но она не работает, в чём проблема?

```css
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['comment'])) 
{
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
    $secondname = htmlentities($_POST['secondname']);
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST['text']);
    $output ="
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Анкетные данные</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    body{
    background: #C5D2DB;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

container{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
 </style>
    <body>
    <container>
    Вас зовут: $name<br />
    Ваша фамилия: $secondname<br />
    Ваш комментарий: $comment<br />
    </container></body></html>";
    echo $output;
}
else
{   
    echo "Введенные данные некорректны";
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Anketa</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <h2>Анкета первокурсника</h2>
<form action="input.php" method="POST">
<p>Введите имя:<br> 
<input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<p>Введите фамилию:<br> 
<input type="text" name="secondname" /></p>
<p>Краткий комментарий: <br>
<textarea name="comment" maxlength="200"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как именно не работает?

Comment: У комментария в одном файле имя comment, а в другом text.

Comment: Пишет ошибку " Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю все работает... исправил name в textarea

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
    $secondname = htmlentities($_POST['secondname']);
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $output ="
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Анкетные данные</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    body{
    background: #C5D2DB;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

container{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
 </style>
    <body>
    <container>
    Вас зовут: $name<br />
    Ваша фамилия: $secondname<br />
    Ваш комментарий: $comment<br />
    </container></body></html>";
    echo $output;
}
else
{   
    echo "Введенные данные некорректны";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anketa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Анкета первокурсника</h2>
<form action="10.php" method="POST">
<p>Введите имя:<br> 
<input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<p>Введите фамилию:<br> 
<input type="text" name="secondname" /></p>
<p>Краткий комментарий: <br>
<textarea name="comment" maxlength="200"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```